# TailwindCSS Intellisense into Neovim

Tags: neovim

I need someone that has tailwindcss-intellisense into neovim, I haven't been able to set it up since yesterday, I might have at this point to build it from scratch.

I followed this two guides:
https://elijahmanor.com/blog/neovim-tailwindcss
https://dyrynda.com.au/blog/neovim-tailwind-intellisense

[image]
[image]

I added it to `$PATH` and is not being detected, both files are executables (`tailwindcss-language-server` and `tailwindServer.js`)

```
NVIM v0.6.1

export PATH=$HOME/thePath:$PATH

/home/c/.config/nvim/extension/dist/server:/home/c/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Comment: Wecome to Vim. Could you add some indications about the symptoms you have? Where in the procedure it fails? What version of Neovim you are using? It will be helpful to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the Welcome, I updated the post with the information required.

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](https://benknoble.github.io/blog/2019/11/24/pics-text/).

Comment: As for the actual issue: does `command -v tailwindcss-language-server` give output like `/path/to/tailwindcss-language-server` or just fail?

Comment: There's no output for `command -v tailwindcss-language-server`